# How to highlight duplicate word in a column in spreadsheet, ignoring text case and Punctuation

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I'm working on a project in excel, but since its a collective data from multiple different person, i want to find any duplicate word after compile it and highlight it. I found a site where it explain about how to Highlight duplicate words in a cell ignoring text case with thing called macro? sorry im new to this, but can it be possible to detect duplicate in one column, ignoring text case and punctuation like "." or "/"?

i just learn the function of macro. Editing the code still confusing.

Comment: Why not check out functions like lower(), proper() and substitute()? lower and proper will change the case and substitute can be used to remove the "." or "/".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Scripting.Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) to implement.

```vb
Sub How_to_highlight_duplicate_word_in_a_column_in_spreadsheet_ignoring_text_case_and_Punctuation()
    Dim cln As Range, ws As Worksheet, c As Range, cv As String, cCollection As New VBA.Collection, key, colr As Long
    Dim cDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    'Dim cDict As Object
    'Set cDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set cln = ws.UsedRange.Columns(3) 'for test
    For Each c In cln.Cells
        cv = c.Value
        If cv <> vbNullString Then
            cv = VBA.StrConv(cv, vbLowerCase)
            RemovePunctuation cv
            If cDict.Exists(cv) Then
                Set cCollection = cDict(cv)
                cCollection.Add c
            Else
                Set cCollection = Nothing
                cCollection.Add c
                cDict.Add cv, cCollection
            End If
        End If
    Next c

    For Each key In cDict.Keys
        Set cCollection = cDict(key)
        If cCollection.Count > 1 Then
            colr = RGB(Int(Rnd * 256), Int(Rnd * 256), Int(Rnd * 256))
            For Each c In cCollection
                ComplementaryColors c, colr
'                With c.Interior
'            '        .Pattern = xlSolid
'            '        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
'                    .Color = colr
'            '        .TintAndShade = 0
'            '        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
'                End With
            Next c
        End If
    Next key
End Sub

Function RemovePunctuation(str As String) As String
    Dim regex As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With regex
        .Pattern = "[^A-Z0-9 ]"
        '.Pattern = "[^\w\s]"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        str = .Replace(str, "")
    End With
    RemovePunctuation = str
End Function

Sub ComplementaryColors(cell As Range, color As Long)
    With cell.Font
        .color = color
'        .color = RGB(255 - color Mod 256, 255 - (color \ 256) Mod 256, 255 - color \ 65536)
    End With
    With cell.Interior
        .color = RGB(255 - color Mod 256, 255 - (color \ 256) Mod 256, 255 - color \ 65536)
    End With
    
End Sub
```